# compare rows and fill gaps with previous values in a data table

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, lag, shift

I have data table that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(time = c(seq(0, 14)),
                   anom = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                   gier = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 7, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0))
```

Now I want to fill the gaps (zeros) with ones in column `anom` so that the result looks like this:

```
res <- data.table(time = c(seq(0, 14)),
                  anom = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                  gier = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 7, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0))
```

In addition there is the problem that I want to be flexible with the gap size so I can choose how big the gap can be. There must be an easy way to do something similar to LOCF only for real values (maybe filling it with the previous value of the row and not only ones or zeros) and not only for NA's like the functions `fill` or `na.locf`.

Comment: @Ronak Shah, it doesn't matter. For me it is only important to set the gap size. In most cases the end values have a lot of zeros. By setting a gap size I can exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

An example using the maxgap argument to select the maximum gap size

```
library(zoo)
na.fill(
  na.locf(
    replace(data$anom,data$anom==0,NA),
    na.rm=F,
    maxgap=2
  ),0
)

 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: this already works great. Is there a more "data.table" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using rolling join:

```
maxgap <- 1L
data[, c("rn", "lu") := .(.I, anom)]
data[anom==0L, lu := fcoalesce(
    data[anom!=0L][.SD, on=.(rn=rn), roll=maxgap, rollends=c(FALSE, FALSE), x.anom],
    anom)
]
```

output:

```
    time anom gier rn lu
 1:    0    0    0  1  0
 2:    1    0    0  2  0
 3:    2    0    0  3  0
 4:    3    1    4  4  1
 5:    4    1    9  5  1
 6:    5    1    7  6  1
 7:    6    0    2  7  1
 8:    7    0    0  8  0
 9:    8    1    3  9  1
10:    9    0    1 10  1
11:   10    1    4 11  1
12:   11    1    2 12  1
13:   12    0    0 13  0
14:   13    0    0 14  0
15:   14    0    0 15  0
```